# How to make GPT extend to the full 3TB a disk has?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gpt, parted

I've got a third party install Linux on my remote server and something went wrong with it. It has a 3TB disk in there:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep size
Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
device size with M = 1024*1024:     2861588 MBytes
device size with M = 1000*1000:     3000592 MBytes (3000 GB)
cache/buffer size  = unknown
```

However, the gpt seems to only recognize 2TB of it:

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 2 TiB, 2199023254528 bytes, 4294967294 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FA1FA25D-68B0-4288-9B4B-7D870C76C3AB

Device         Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048     999423     997376  487M EFI System
/dev/sda2     999424  196311039  195311616 93.1G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3  196311040 4294967260 4098656221  1.9T Linux filesy
```

Same with parted:

```
# parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: ATA WDC WD30EFRX-68E (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      512MB   101GB   100GB                      raid
 3      101GB   2199GB  2099GB
```

How can I make the gpt extend to the full 3TB? There is no data on the machine yet and it is not the only disk (as in, the system will survive losing all data on the disk), but I would like to be able to fix this remotely.

Edit: additional commands requested:

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0     2T  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0   487M  0 part  /boot/efi
└─sda2    8:2    0  93.1G  0 part
  └─md0   9:0    0  93.1G  0 raid1 /


# blockdev --getsz /dev/sda
4294967294

# hdparm -N /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 max sectors   = 5860533168/5860533168, HPA is disabled
```

Edit: I've deleted the device with

```
echo 1 > /sys/block/sda/device/delete
```

and rescanned with

```
echo "0 0 0" >  /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
```

but actually the kernel thinks it is 2TB

```
[1163699.012539] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      WDC WD30EFRX-68E 0A80 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[1163699.016198] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[1163699.016582] sd 0:0:0:0: [sde] 4294967294 512-byte logical blocks: (2.19 TB/1.99 TiB)
[1163699.021485] sd 0:0:0:0: [sde] Write Protect is off
[1163699.021490] sd 0:0:0:0: [sde] Mode Sense: 73 00 00 08
[1163699.022765] sd 0:0:0:0: [sde] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
```

I'm wondering if simply the kernel in Debian Jessie is just too old to see the 3TB.

Edit: nope, at kernel version 4.7.8 I still get only 2TiB.

Comment: What do `lsblk` and `blockdev --getsz` say about it?

Comment: How about `dhparm -N /dev/sda`?

Comment: Adding to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that is a problem with the machine, not the software stack. It uses LSISAS1068E controller, which apparently limits the drives to 2.2TB. I am searching for a way around this, but it is pretty much unrelated to anything tried so far.

Comment: Thank you. Just ran into the same issue with the same controller unfortunately...